# Play Framework automatically deletes all records in the database when you run unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, playframework

Whenever I run Automated Tests on my site, all the tables get cleaned to 0 rows. Is that by design? How do I prevent them?

Update: Found the real 'culprit'
%test.jpa.ddl=create

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is by design. Unit tests should not have any external dependencies on some pre-existing state such as persisted data. If you need data for testing purposes, you need to set that up in your `@Before` setup method. For example:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    // The following loads test data from the YAML file
    Fixtures.loadModels("test-data/users.yml");
}

@Test
public void someTest() {
    assertEquals(5, User.count()); // 5 User records exist due to @Before method
}
```

You should take a look at your conf/application.conf file and notice that you have a line that reads:

```
%test.db=mem
```

This is the default setting - which says that when the application is run in test mode, use an in-memory database. If you want your tests to work on persisted data (not recommended), you can change the test mode db settings. See [Play test documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/test) for details.

Comment: Actually, the real 'culprit' was %test.jpa.ddl=create

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until I updated application.conf file:

```
%test.jpa.ddl=none
```

https://playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/configuration#jpa